# Writing a Chrome extension and trying to communicate between popover script and content script unsuccessfully, why are my messages failing?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, browser, message, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have a very simple Chrome extension that is just sending a message from the popover.html's javascript to the content script, and then changing a div on the page to output that, but I keep getting undefined.

popup.js:

```js
browser.runtime.sendMessage({ test: "foo2" }).then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
    document.getElementById("testp").innerHTML = response; // writes out 'undefined'
});
```

content.js:

```js
browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
    sendResponse({test: "foo" });
});
```

popup.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script type="module" src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="testp">pleasechangeme</p>
</body>
</html>
```

What's wrong with my messaging that is causing it to write out undefined in the HTML each time? I'm not touching the DOM anywhere so I don't think it's related to that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sendMessage from popup to content.js not working in chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29926598/sendmessage-from-popup-to-content-js-not-working-in-chrome-extension)

Comment: @MlungisiNdlela No because I'm not accessing the DOM

Comment: Look at the example there: you need to use chrome.tabs.sendMessage not chrome.runtime.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I see that did work