# I'm rather confused by how content scripts and background scripts in chrome ext interact, as I am able to make each work individually but not together

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I have simplified and shortened my code so that it may be clear

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["contentscript.js"]
    }
  ],
  "background": {
    "js": "scroll.js"
  },
  "permissions": ["activeTab","tabs"]
}
```

**contentscript.js**

```
var scrollDirection = '';

// A way to read background.js

if(scrollDirection=='up'){
  scrollToTop();
}
else if(scrollDirection=='down'){
  scrollToBottom();
}

function scrollToTop() {
  console.log('u');
  setInterval(function() {
    window.scrollBy(0, 1);
  }, 10);
}

function scrollToBottom() {
  console.log('d');
  setInterval(function() {
    window.scrollBy(0, -1);
  }, 10);
}
```

**scroll.js**

```
var btnu = document.getElementById("ScrollU");
var btnd = document.getElementById("ScrollD");
var scrollDirection = '';

btnu.addEventListener('click', function() {
  scrollDirection = 'up';
  // A way to send a message to content.js
});

btnd.addEventListener('click', function() {
  scrollDirection = 'down';
  // A way to send a message to content.js
});
```

**popup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="ScrollU">Scroll Up</button>
    <button id="ScrollD">Scroll Down</button>    
    <script src="scroll.js"></script>
    <script src="contentscript.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any Help would be appreciated :) but I need to send a (chrome.tab message) or (window.message) (I tried both but they didn't really work) or so and any formatting error or structural error you see. Thank you !

I know that my contentscript.js file can scroll a page, I know that my scroll.js can read button clicks, so it must be some sort off structural issue prohibiting the message between the two (assuming you can send one from contentscript to background) Like I said any help would be greatly appreaciated :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sendMessage from popup to content.js not working in chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29926598/sendmessage-from-popup-to-content-js-not-working-in-chrome-extension)

Comment: 1) The background script is only necessary to listen to chrome.xxxx events, to put it simply. It's not for the popup's events, so remove `background` section from manifest.json. 2) The content script runs in the web page, not in the popup, so remove `<script` tag for contentscript.js. 3) Use messaging or executeScript to control the content script.

Comment: Hey, I made all the changes and by some miracle it worked I'm not sure what exactly the problem was but genuinely tysm :) and yes that resource did help